# How to stop reload interval after x second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using datatable and there is an option to use `setInterval` in order to refresh the table content.

The problem is, that the network traffic is increasing when the user stays on that page and if the page is doing a consistent reload every second of the same dataset.

I want to stop after 10 seconds, because I think this is the average time a user stays on that page before going somewhere else.

Not sure how to include the 10 second timeout, below is my code so far:

```
setInterval(function() {
        $('#Table1').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply cancel the `setInterval` after 10 seconds pass (using `setTimeout`). You can clear an interval timer using `clearInterval`.

```
var refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
   $('#Table1').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(refreshInterval);
}, 1000 * 10);
```

The asynchronous nature of JavaScript enables both `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to run at the appropriate times and without one blocking the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#Table1').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(interval); }, 10000);
```

Example code snippet:

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Interval fired");
}, 1000);
    
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(interval); }, 10000);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $('#Table1').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    }, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
   clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 10000);
```

I suggest that you use a setTimeout function in the response callback of your Ajax call and have a count variable that counts to 10 each time setTimeout is executed, and clearInterval when count reaches 10. This would be more efficient if your request takes a longer time to process.

Comment: Thanks, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

First `var foo = setInterval(...`

and then stop it after 3 seconds `setTimeout(function(){ clearInterval(foo); }, 3000);`